# error message when using setting variables with the enum class

Tags: java, class, enums

I am trying to set Cell to the ONE variable I placed in the enum class, but it says "ONE cannot be resolved or it is not a field" the same message occurs all over my code when I try to set Cell.ONE or Cell.TWO, nothing works, but it has no problem setting GameStatus...I don't see how when I use the GameStatus enum it works and the Cell class it doesn't. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
// No imports

private Cell[][] board;
private Cell turn;
private int size;
private GameStatus status;

public enum Cell {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, EMPTY
} 

public enum GameStatus {
    PLAYER1_WON, PLAYER2_WON, PLAYER3_WON, PLAYER4_WON, PLAYER5_WON,
    PLAYER6_WON, PLAYER7_WON, PLAYER8_WON, PLAYER9_WON, TIE, 
    IN_PROGRESS
}    

public SurroundGame(int size) {
        status = GameStatus.IN_PROGRESS; 
        board = new Cell[size][size];
        turn = Cell.ONE; *ONE cannot be resolved or it is not a field*
        reset();
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you're `import`-ing the wrong `Cell`?

Comment: Can you please post your `import` statements? I suspect you have imported another class called `Cell`

Comment: Please show your imports, and show your exact error message. What does it say in the console?

Comment: Please edit and post a **complete** minimal sample reproducing the issue, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: No imports, and there is no other Cell class, it just doesn't make sense...

Comment: @CodyTimmer is your IDE giving you an error, or is it the error outputted into the console?  If it's your IDE, it may just be a bug with the compilation.

Comment: @Loafayyy sorry I'm not sure how to tell if it's IDE or console what do you mean? I am using eclipse and it is showing the red x next to each line that contains Cell.(variable) and giving the same error message

Comment: I've brought your code into my StackOverflow project and don't have any problems with the enum.  I went as far as creating an instances and added a getTurn() so I could print out a value in case it was hitting you at instantiation, but I didn't hit any errors.

Comment: Does it make a difference that the 2 enum classes are separate files under the same project in eclipse? I don't see why it would...and why GameStatus would work and Cell doesn't

Comment: So they are separate class files in the project?  Are they all in the same package?

Comment: @CodyTimmer sometimes with eclipse, you may have compilation errors in the code.  It only seems logical that it would be an error with the compilation because GameStatus compiles, but Cell doesn't.  To fix this, try selecting Project > Clean Project in the eclipse menu.

Comment: Cleaned, still not working, can I not import more than 1 enum class at a time?

Comment: @CodyTimmer I thought you didn't have any imports, why would that make a difference?

Comment: Well I'm mind blown, after 2 hours of trying to move around code, cutting, copying and pasting and trying to get this thing to work, I just decided to run it, it worked, I go back and the errors are gone...thanks eclipse...still don't know why it had an issue before and kept giving me errors, thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Ah the infamous "Eclipse is lying" status :)

Answer (score 0):

`Cell` shouldn't necesserily be previously declared as a `class` for this error to occur. It can be, say, a field:

```
GameStatus Cell;

public SurroundGame(int size) {
    status = GameStatus.IN_PROGRESS; 
    board = new Cell[size][size];
    turn = Cell.ONE; /*ONE cannot be resolved or it is not a field*/
}
```

Gives a similar error.

Check and double-check all of your fields. You've most probably got one called Cell somewhere in the class.

Comment: I am 100% sure there is no other Cell variable anywhere in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full class I brought in, in case it helps you somehow, it runs fine for me...

```
public class Answer28535890 {

public static class SurroundGame
{
    private Cell[][] board;
    private Cell turn;
    private int size;
    private GameStatus status;

    public enum Cell {
        ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, EMPTY
    } 

    public enum GameStatus {
        PLAYER1_WON, PLAYER2_WON, PLAYER3_WON, PLAYER4_WON, PLAYER5_WON,
        PLAYER6_WON, PLAYER7_WON, PLAYER8_WON, PLAYER9_WON, TIE, 
        IN_PROGRESS
    }    

    public SurroundGame(int size) {
            status = GameStatus.IN_PROGRESS; 
            board = new Cell[size][size];
            turn = Cell.ONE; 
            reset();
    }

    public void reset()
    {

    }

    public Cell getTurn()
    {
        return turn;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SurroundGame sg = new SurroundGame(3);
    System.out.println(sg.getTurn());
}

}
```

Comment: I can move the Enums out of here as well, separate enum classes within the overall file or even separate class files within the package.  The only time I hit a problem is if I  move them out of the package and don't include an import.

Comment: It works when it is like this, but my Cell and Gamestatus classes are in separate files in the project, it has to be like this because they are both accessed in other classes besides the SurroundGame class.